# Export and get data from API in Google Earth Engine

Tags: api, rest, google-earth-engine

i use google earth engine. i have manage to export data to csv in my google drive.
However , i was wondering if is possible to have an api (https request -json type) to get the data.
i need this option because i need to access the data (real time data) a few times per day  , to import them in other system for analysis.
Is that possible?

Thanks in advance!